# How to Have both Header and BottomTabNavigator in functional component in ReactNative?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I want to have both BottomTabNavigator and the default Header that is generated by createStrackNavigator.

my problem is that when I try to use both of these options one gets ignored and react-navigation docs are all based on class component and I cant work it out.

here is my navigator.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import {createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import RegisterLoginScreen from './views/RegisterLoginScreen/RegisterLoginScreen';
import ConfirmCodeScreen from './views/ConfirmCodeScreen/ConfrimCodeScreen';
import QRCodeScreen from './views/QRCodeBuy/QRCodeBuyScreen';
import ServicesScreen from './views/ServicesScreen/ServicesScreen';
import ProfileEditScreen from './views/ProfileEditScreen/ProfileEditScreen';
import TransactionScreen from './views/TransactionScreen/TransactionScreen';

const HeaderNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  RegisterLogin: RegisterLoginScreen,
  confirmCode: ConfirmCodeScreen,
  QRBuy: QRCodeScreen,

});
const BottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  ProfileEdit: ProfileEditScreen,
  Services: ServicesScreen,
  Transactions:TransactionScreen,
  QRBuy: QRCodeScreen,
});
const AppSwitch = createSwitchNavigator({
  BottomTabNavigator: BottomTabNavigator,
  Header:HeaderNavigator

});

export default createAppContainer(AppSwitch);
```

QRScreen.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';

const QRCodeBuyScreen = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>This is qr screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
QRCodeBuyScreen.navigationOptions = () => ({
  title:'بارکد',
  headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#CD0448',
  },
});
QRCodeBuyScreen.tabBarOptions = () => ({
  activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
  labelStyle: {
    fontSize: 12,
  },
  style: {
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
  },
});

export default QRCodeBuyScreen;
```

is there a way to have both in a screen? or any work around?

Comment: I think it's not possible to combine the both Header Title, Try to fix one and put the title that you want

Comment: I fould my answer actually I'll post it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I leave the answer here I found myself. the key here is to nest the navigations inside each other and then pass one as the higher order navigation and one nested inside the higher order nav

so for example if you want something like this

```
headerTab{
   login
   confirm otp => bottomTab{
    first{},
    second{},
    third{} // each can have their own stack of screens 
 }
}
```

you need to configure the navigator like below:

```
import React from 'react';
import {createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation-tabs';

import LandingScreen from './views/SplashLandingScreen/SplashLanding';
import AboutScreen from './views/AboutScreen/AboutScreen';
import RegisterLoginScreen from './views/RegisterLoginScreen/RegisterLoginScreen';
import ConfirmCodeScreen from './views/ConfirmCodeScreen/ConfrimCodeScreen';
import userProfileScreen from './views/userProfileScreen/userProfileScreen';
import QRCodeScreen from './views/QRCodeBuy/QRCodeBuyScreen';
import ServicesScreen from './views/ServicesScreen/ServicesScreen';
import WalletScreen from './views/WalletScreen/Wallet';
import MyQRCodeScreen from './views/MyQRCode/MyQRCodeScreen';
import ProfileEditScreen from './views/ProfileEditScreen/ProfileEditScreen';
import TransactionScreen from './views/TransactionScreen/TransactionScreen';
import Msg from './views/Messages/Messegaes';

const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Landing: LandingScreen,
  RegisterLogin: RegisterLoginScreen,
  confirmCode: ConfirmCodeScreen,
});

const ProfileStack = createStackNavigator({
  Profile: userProfileScreen,
  ProfileEdit: ProfileEditScreen,
  MyQR: MyQRCodeScreen,
  Wallet: WalletScreen,
  About: AboutScreen,
  Msg: Msg,
},);
const BottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    userProfile: ProfileStack,
    Services: ServicesScreen,
    Transaction: TransactionScreen,
    QRBuy: QRCodeScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'QRBuy',
  },
);
const AppSwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  StackNavigator: StackNavigator,
  BottomTabNavigator: BottomTabNavigator,
});
export default createAppContainer(AppSwitchNavigator);
```